# jmeter pass multiple values to variable in Body Data

Tags: jmeter

In HTTP Request Body Data I want to set variable that can have multiple values.

For example drivers license variable (having yes/no option). How do I define a variable having these options and each thread having random selection out of these two options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using UDV:**

- Create [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) as shown below for the each possible option.

[image]

- The 'Body Data' section of the HTTP Request should be as shown below to get the random option values at run time.

  ```
  {
      "license" : "${__V(option_${__Random(1,3,)})}"
  }
  ```
- Check for functions: [Random](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) and [V](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V)
- I see below requests sent.

  ```
  {
      "license" : "yes" 
  }
  ```

  OR

  ```
  {
      "license" : "no" 
  }
  ```

Comment: Just a slight improvement - Random(1,3,) should be Random(1,2,) . In JMeter random function is inclusive for both the min and max.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [__javaScript()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function. Wherever you want random "yes" or "no" use the following construction:

```
${__javaScript(var yesno = ['yes'\,'no']; yesno[Math.floor(Math.random()*yesno.length)],)}
```

Demo:

[image: JavaScript Random]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series for more information on above and others JMeter Functions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use CSV data set config and configure a variable name with file
2. Write Yes and no in the txt file by next next lines like below

yes
no

Use that variable name used in csv dataset config in params, so that first thread will take "yes" and second thread will take "no" - You can use more threads to take different values.

Note: Recycle on EOF should be TRUE in CSV dataset config.